# How do I pass javascript to PHP on a javascript command?

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP, but I'm developing in Visual Studio LightSwitch.
I'd like to pass several javascript variables from a data record to a PHP script during a javascript save event.

What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

Your options are limited to ajax, or an image request.

Option 1. AJAX

```
function success() {
  console.log(this.responseText);
}

var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.onload = success;
// myVars is a string containing the values you  need to record. In the format
// of ?var=value&var1=value&var2=value
ajax.open("get", "/record.php?" + myVars, true);
ajax.send();
```

Option 2. Image

```
   var a = document.getElementById('my-button');
   a.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
     var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
     var img = new Image();
     // get your variables values and create a url here.

     img.src = 'http://myserver.tld/record.php?' + myVars;
   });
```